# Having trouble with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (wrong name:) when running from cmd

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and as the title says I'm struggling to run my Test program (it's basically just a hello world program) from the cmd, I'm using the directory of `myfolder\eclipse\learning\src\learning` to store my project classes/.java files.
I get the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: learning/Test (wrong name: Test)
```

I'm not sure why, I've done "javac Test.java", and that goes fine, but whenever I try "java Test" I get that error. I've also tried "java Test.class" but that just gave me the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test.class
```

The class also runs fine in Eclipse. I've googled this problem many times and have found no solution, but I could just somehow be using those solutions incorrectly.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please show the code for `Test.java`. Specifically, is the first line a `package` statement?

Comment: [Getting Started](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) trail in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Comment: How do you compile your Test program?

Comment: You wrote in your question: _The class also runs fine in Eclipse_. Choose item ___Run Configurations...___ from the _Run_ menu in Eclipse. In the _Run Configurations_ window, click on the _Show Command Line_ button. It will open a window displaying the command that Eclipse uses in order to run your class.

Answer (score 1):

Compile is as follows:

```
myfolder\eclipse\learning\src\learning\>javac -d . Test.java
```

Run it as follows:

```
myfolder\eclipse\learning\src\learning\>java learning.Test
```

**Notes:**

1. `-d` specifies where to place generated class files.
2. `.` stands for current directory

Note that if you are using Java 11, you can run it directly as `java Test.java` even without compiling it. Check [this](https://www.infoq.com/articles/single-file-execution-java11/) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the first line of `Test.java` is:

```
package learning;
```

To run this class after you compile it, you need to be in the `myfolder\eclipse\learning\src` directory. Then run it with `java learning.Test`. This is because you have created the class inside a package as shown by the package declaration. Eclipse is built to understand packages and does the right thing automatically for you. That's why you don't get any errors running in Eclipse.